# Add menu image instead of text to sidr plugin

Tags: jquery, menu, sidr

Hello I am using SIDR plugin to add a toggle menu to my site. I want to use an image that visitors can click on and the toggle menu opens. I am wrapping the image in the a tag with the id of #simple-menu. However the image doesnt display. Does any body know why?

hello

Comment: Could you post what your current markup and code looks like? An example using JSBin or JSFiddle might be helpful as well.

Comment: <a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr"><img src"http://vanecharles5.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/music_teacher_reviews_nabi_brown.png"></a>
<div id="sidr">
  <!-- Your content -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I feel so dumb!

I had a mistake in my code. I didnt add equal signs to the src attribute, so i had

```
<img src"">
```

instead of

```
<img src="">
```